# Why does "http://function URL() {[native code]}" get injected via $(selector).html()?

Tags: jquery, node.js

I have a basic GET call to my backend via jQuery, like so: `$.get("http://whatever.herokuapp.com/products", function(html) {}`, which gets handled in a `Node.js` route handler by calling code that fetches a product record from a `MongoDB` database. This product data is then built up with some HTML, and is sent back as an HTML string, whereupon it is injected into the page via a `$("#products").html(html)` call.

This HTML string has a URL in it (a link to the product on some eCommerce site). But, instead of the URL being rendered as the usual `http://www.somemerchant.com/productid=12345&whatever=2`, it gets mangled into `http://function URL() {[native code]}`.

Anyone have any idea what would cause this to happen? I have checked the return every step of the way - from the raw data extracted from `MongoDB`, to the HTML string created and sent back to `Node.js` handler, to what's returned by `Node.js` via `response.send()`, to what results from the `$.get()` call, and everything is fine - the URL is as it should be. If i change the `$("#products").html(html)` call to `$("#products").text(html)`, again, everything is fine - the HTML is rendered as text, but the URL is intact. It's at this point - `$("#products").html(html)` - that the URL gets mangled. And i have no idea why.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: It's not a string, it's a function, so it's converted in node by `toString()` to the string equalent, which would be `function URL() {[native code]}`

Comment: did you try executing the `URL` function instead of passing it?

Comment: Do not see any relation to mongodb

Comment: Try escaping the URL.

Comment: @adeneo, when you say "It's not a string", to what is "it" referring? Are you saying that the HTML string that I generate and pass back to the page isn't actually a string? What is the actual function, and what is it that's being converted in node to the string equivalent? Feels like this is the answer here, but I just want to be clear on what you're referring to. Thank you for taking the time to reply - appreciate it!

Comment: node.js uses toString internally for certain things, like when you're trying to output something etc. or when you're trying to add something to a string, it's automatically converted to a string, even functions are, and a function that is "stringified" outputs exactly what you say you have, so you're trying to add the function it self to a string -> http://jsfiddle.net/BrjFQ/

Comment: Got it. OK, will try to find where this is happening and fix it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are might missing the `()` somewhere in your code. This causes node (or the browser) to print the function code. Native functions are not fully printed, instead it prints only the string `[native code]`.

We might give you better help if you provide the code your are working on.

Below is an example of what is happening (this was ran from Chrome's console):

[image: Example]

Comment: OK, feels like a good candidate for exploration; i will go through the code and look for missing (). Thanks for your reply!